# Call method from UITableView Cell subView in iphone application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

i have iphone application in which i am adding button to cell what i want when i click on that button it should give me the title of that button in button action.

```
if (tableView==groupTableView) {
        GroupData*theData=[groupArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
        cell.textLabel.text=theData.GroupTitle;

        addButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        //[tab1 setFrame:CGRectMake(-1,2,293,58)];

        addButton.Frame=CGRectMake(400,2,42,42);

        [addButton setTitle:@"Record Video" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tab1Action) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [addButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"popuptab1j.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        addButton.clipsToBounds=YES;           
        [cell addSubview:addButton];

        return cell;     
}

-(void)tab1Action {    
     NSLog(@"Cell Tab1 Clicked %@",clicked);
}
```

It show groupTitle of selected button when I click this add button then it show the group title of the cell whom button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set you button in UITableViewCell with Tag like bellow:-

```
    addButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    addButton.Frame=CGRectMake(400,2,42,42);

    [addButton setTitle:@"Record Video" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tab1Action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    addButton.tag=indexPath.row;
    [addButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"popuptab1j.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    addButton.clipsToBounds=YES;
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:addButton];



    -(IBAction)tab1Action:(UIButton *)sender
    { 
        NSLog(@"=== >  %d",sender.tag);
    //apple your Logic
    }
```

**NOTE:-** use  `[[cell contentView] addSubview:addButton];` instead of use  `[cell addSubview:addButton];` and also you not setting proper Button frame for iPhone 400 is out or screen width.

Comment: given errro at tab1Action sender.tag

Comment: sorry forget to add UIButton* ref replace your tab1action with -(IBAction)tab1Action:(UIButton *)sender

Comment: [RootViewController tab1Action]: urecognized action sent